# android Textview text background colour like WebSites

Tags: android, textview

[output i'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaoJk.png)I'm creating app in which I'm setting background color of `textview` using BackgroundColorSpan. But it's output different than i want.

**Code**

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(inputTextView.getText()); 
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(a); 
spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, 0, inputTextView.getText().toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
inputTextView.setText(spannable);
```

And

```
String s ="<span style='background-color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 2.0;'>"+inputTextView.getText()+"</span>";   
inputTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Screenshot of website text i want to make in android

[image]

Comment: add your code what ever you try.

Comment: String s ="<span style='background-color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 2.0;'>"+inputTextView.getText()+"</span>";


           inputTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));

Comment: Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(inputTextView.getText());
            BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(a);
            spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, 0, inputTextView.getText().toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            inputTextView.setText(spannable);

Comment: edit your question and add your code their, not here in comments

Comment: you can show image also on textview then only image show textview that make type of style.

Comment: but text and  it's background colour  is dynamic  so putting an  image won't work

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundColorSpan()` uses hex value. You need to convert your hash string to hex and use it.

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(inputTextView.getText().toString()); 
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")); 
spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, 0, inputTextView.getText().toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
inputTextView.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: @thomas: is it a hex value?

Comment: yes it's hex value and also working but output is different than screenshot

Comment: output is different than i want.